# Error en la creación de archivo

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python y me encuentro con el siguiente error al tratar de crear un .txt y escribir en el:

*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory*

Código ejecutado:

```
from io import open

archivo_texto=open("arhivo.txt" , "W")

frase="Esto es una prueba"

archivo_texto.write(frase)
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La W tiene que ser minúscula. Además, sería recomendable cerrar el fichero al terminar el programa. Te paso el código para que puedas ejecutarlo:

```
from io import open

archivo_texto=open("arhivo.txt" , "w")

frase="Esto es una prueba"

archivo_texto.write(frase)

archivo_texto.close()
```

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, sigo obteniendo el mismo error, he comprobado que las versiones de instalación son las últimas y sigo sin hallar la solución

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da el error? ¿Al crear el fichero o al escribir en él? ¿Puede ser que tengas permisos de sólo lectura en el directorio en el que estás trabajando?

Comment: En línea 3 al intentar crear : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arhivo.txt'. He revisado los permisos y los tiene todos.

Comment: Solucionado: reinstalación.

Comment: Qué bien @AIV, me alegra que se haya resuelto...

Comment: ¡Hola! Yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema. Es muy extraño, porque ayer me funcionaba y hoy ha dejado de hacerlo. Estoy utilizando un path absoluto. Veo que comentas que has solucionado reinstalando, ¿pero qué exactamente? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: @ailoher creo que deberias preguntarlo fuera de los comentarios. Aqui normalmente no se ve ni responde pregunta(Cuando uno pregunta el sitio lo pone en la cima de las pregunta, pero los comentarios no)

Comment: @ailoher ha, 4años ¿como te fue?